# C++ convert struct hostent.h_addr_list IP to sockaddr struct

Tags: c++, linux, struct

In my linux C++ application I have hostent struct which contains h_addr_list.
I want the IP h_addr_list contains to be contain in struct sockaddr. do you know how to do it?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`gethostby*()` is an ancient relict. If you use `getaddrinfo`/`getnameinfo` instead, you get a proper `struct sockaddr`.

```
struct addrinfo *res;
getaddrinfo("hostname", NULL, NULL, &res);
/* then see res->ai_addr */
```

Comment: I have only the IP from getpeername and the only systemcall that works for me is gethostbyname.